# PMD plugin fails after upgrading Sonarqube to 4.5.4

Tags: java, ant, sonarqube, pmd

I am **upgrading** my existing **SonarQube** 3.7.4 installation to the new **LTS release 4.5.4**.
I'd like to reuse my ruleset and I am using the sonarqube ant task (as before) to analyze my projects.

After upgrading the sonar installation and the ant task to 2.2 without changing anything else I'm getting a **`NoClassDefFoundError`** while executing the ant task:

```
build.xml:1659: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.launchAnalysis(SonarTask.java:53)
        at org.sonar.ant.SonarTask.execute(SonarTask.java:48)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManager
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:412)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.PMDASMClassLoader.loadClass(PMDASMClassLoader.java:62)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.TypeSet$ExplicitImportResolver.resolve(TypeSet.java:93)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.TypeSet.findClass(TypeSet.java:265)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.SourceFileScope.resolveType(SourceFileScope.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.ClassScope.determineParameterTypes(ClassScope.java:217)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.ClassScope.findVariableHere(ClassScope.java:142)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.AbstractJavaScope.contains(AbstractJavaScope.java:33)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.Search.searchUpward(Search.java:45)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.Search.searchUpward(Search.java:49)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.Search.searchUpward(Search.java:49)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.Search.searchUpward(Search.java:49)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.Search.searchUpward(Search.java:49)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.Search.execute(Search.java:24)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.OccurrenceFinder.visit(OccurrenceFinder.java:26)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTPrimaryExpression.jjtAccept(ASTPrimaryExpression.java:22)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:372)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTStatementExpression.jjtAccept(ASTStatementExpression.java:22)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:348)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTStatement.jjtAccept(ASTStatement.java:22)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:360)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTBlockStatement.jjtAccept(ASTBlockStatement.java:22)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:356)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTBlock.jjtAccept(ASTBlock.java:22)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:432)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTTryStatement.jjtAccept(ASTTryStatement.java:23)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:348)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTStatement.jjtAccept(ASTStatement.java:22)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:360)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTBlockStatement.jjtAccept(ASTBlockStatement.java:22)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:356)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTBlock.jjtAccept(ASTBlock.java:22)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:180)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTMethodDeclaration.jjtAccept(ASTMethodDeclaration.java:25)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:45)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration.jjtAccept(ASTClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration.java:41)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:41)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTClassOrInterfaceBody.jjtAccept(ASTClassOrInterfaceBody.java:22)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:17)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.jjtAccept(ASTClassOrInterfaceDeclaration.java:26)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:156)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTTypeDeclaration.jjtAccept(ASTTypeDeclaration.java:36)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:136)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTCompilationUnit.jjtAccept(ASTCompilationUnit.java:42)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.symboltable.SymbolFacade.initializeWith(SymbolFacade.java:16)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.AbstractJavaHandler$4.start(AbstractJavaHandler.java:79)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.symbolFacade(SourceCodeProcessor.java:100)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSource(SourceCodeProcessor.java:139)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:76)
        at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:43)
        at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdTemplate.process(PmdTemplate.java:83)
        at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executeRules(PmdExecutor.java:119)
        at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executePmd(PmdExecutor.java:89)
        at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.execute(PmdExecutor.java:75)
        at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdSensor.analyse(PmdSensor.java:67)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:119)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:194)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:233)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:221)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:64)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:51)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:125)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:173)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 144 more
```

Why does this happen? What I am doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two problems showing up.

First, PMD doesn't handle the NoClassDefFoundError similar to ClassNotFoundException - I've created an issue for PMD [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1319/).

Second, Sonar doesn't seem to provide the complete project classpath to PMD. In order for PMD to be able to take advantage of typeresolution, PMD can be provided with an extra classpath (at the command line that's the auxclasspath option). Sonar creates the classpath in [PmdExecutor](https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-pmd/blob/master/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/pmd/PmdExecutor.java)'s method "createClassloader", which uses a [JavaResourceLocator](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-squid/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/DefaultJavaResourceLocator.java) which in turn uses [JavaClasspath](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java/blob/master/java-squid/src/main/java/org/sonar/java/JavaClasspath.java). This uses - in case of a maven project - the project's compile classpath, which should include the missing JPA dependency that you observe. For non-maven project, there seems to be a settings property, that you can use to add additional libraries to the classpath: `sonar.java.libraries`. I'd try to add the missing JPA dependency there.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed analysis and issue creation. Your proposed sonar workaround helped me. However - this PMD bug seems to be a regression which must have been introduced within the last 2 years, because older releases seem not to suffer from this problem.