# Execution error using gradle sonarqube plugin

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube-4.5

SonarQube execution fails for some reason. But I cannot understand why.
The analysis has worked fine previously but all of a sudden this error happens every single time (the only thing that has changed since it was working is the code being analyzed)

Server:

- SonarQube 4.5.4 (should probably not matter in this case)
- PMD plugin 2.3

Client:

- Gradle 2.x (tried 2.2, 2.4, 2.6)
- Multi-module project (android)
- org.sonarqube.gradle:gradle-sonarqube-plugin:1.0
- Client OS (TeamCity build agent): Linux, version 3.13.0-52-generic

Client error log (partial):

```
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] 14:04:06.125 INFO  - Execute PMD 5.2.1 done: 2731 ms
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] :sonarqube FAILED
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] :sonarqube (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 28.276 secs.
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] 
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] 
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] * What went wrong:
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] > Unable to execute Sonar
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] 
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] * Try:
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] Run with --debug option to get more log output.
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] 
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] * Exception is:
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
...
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.app.Service
[16:05:28][Step 3/3]    ... 154 more
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] 
[16:05:28][Step 3/3] Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
[16:05:29][Step 3/3] Received result DaemonCommandResult[type=CommandFailure, value=org.gradle.launcher.exec.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=23443, address=[ec2724a7-72a9-4431-9625-d454f3bd053c port:47788, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, /127.0.0.1]], idle=false, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=87652ca6-5d94-436f-b633-630f97c81e4c,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle,daemonRegistryDir=/home/buildagent/.gradle/daemon,pid=23443,idleTimeout=120000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m,-Dfile.encoding=US-ASCII,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}.
[16:05:29][Step 3/3] Process exited with code 1
[16:05:29][Step 3/3] Step Sonar Report (Command Line) failed
```

Comment: If you revert your code changes, does it pass again?

Comment: It does. And the code change should really not affect. Two new test classes and two changes to existing classes. I'm suspecting that some process does not have enough resources...

Comment: Can you try to enable debug logs?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ZsUs3yLJ

Comment: Seems related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28903955/pmd-plugin-fails-after-upgrading-sonarqube-to-4-5-4

Comment: I will update the PMD plugin to 2.4.1 and try again. Will post the result here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is a [known issue in PMD](https://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1319/).

Updating the PMD plugin in SonarQube from version 2.3 to 2.4.1 solved my problem.